# Using Jquery to perform a composite AJAX request

Tags: rest-api, jquery

I have been building an application that utilises Salesforce's REST APIs and have been successful with all API requests except composite, which I keep getting a 404 back on. I have stripped the request down as much as I can and the code is below.

```
    $.ajax({  
          type: 'POST',  
          url : 'https://eu11.salesforce.com/services/data/v37.0/composite/batch/',  
          data: {  
              "batchRequests" : [{  
                                    "method" : "GET",  
                                    "url" : "v37.0/sobjects/Account/describe"  
                                }]  
          },  
          headers : {  
              'Authorization' : 'Bearer '+sx.access_token,  
              'Content-Type' : 'application/json'  
          },  
          success : function(response){  
              console.log(response)              
          }  
 });
```

Is anyone able to notice where I may have gone wrong?

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: just remove `sobjects` from the URL in the AJAX request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove `sobject` from the request:

```
$.ajax({  
   type: 'POST',  
   url : 'https://eu11.salesforce.com/services/data/v37.0/composite/batch/',  
   data: {  
      "batchRequests" : [{  
                            "method" : "GET",  
                            "url" : "v34.0/sobjects/Account/describe"  
                        }]  
   },  
   headers : {  
      'Authorization' : 'Bearer '+sx.access_token,  
      'Content-Type' : 'application/json'  
   },  
   success : function(response){  
       console.log(response)              
   }  
});
```

It worked for me.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how that ended up in there and how I missed it. However I now seem to be getting 400 errors back on it as it doesn't seem to like the way the data has been formatted:-   

[{"errorCode":"JSON_PARSER_ERROR","message":"Unexpected character ('b' (code 98)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null') at [line:1, column:2]"}]

Comment: a small update you need...just replace keys in the json using double quotes...missed to update that...updated the answer now...

Comment: also, there is no composite batch for `"v34.0/sobjects"`

Comment: I did try with the quotes and still getting the same error with your updated code.

Comment: added screenshot in the answer...just verify if you missed anything...i dont think anything is missing...

Comment: They seem identical as far as I can tell and tried various variations with the same error.

Comment: can you update the question with the new code please?

Comment: Code has been edited to what I'm currently using to test this API request